# Make :Wq equivalent to :wq in vim

Tags: vim, alias

I'm always typing `:Wq` when I mean `:wq`. Is there a way to `alias :Wq=':wq'` in vim?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but I aliased `;` to `:` instead.

```
nnoremap ; :
```

(Why worry about not releasing <kbd>Shift</kbd> in time if you can just *not* press it in the first place.)

A more direct answer:

```
command Wq :wq
```

(As it happens, user-defined commands *must* start with an upper-case letter.)

You'll likely want proper tab-completion though, as well as `:W`:

```
command -complete=file -bang -nargs=? W  :w<bang> <args>
command -complete=file -bang -nargs=? Wq :wq<bang> <args>
```

Comment: This is a line to be added in `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: Since I tend to have a "lazy shift finger" when typing a colon, I have had to create user-commands that correspond to a number of internal Vim commands, including `:Help`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answers for the [same question on the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817501/remapping-wq-to-wq-in-vim) on how to achieve what you asked.

But I think it is better to use `ZZ` (which is also mentioned there), as it is shorter to type and avoid the problem altogether. Mappings are usually better than commands for frequent actions/tasks.

Comment: Thanks @mMontu. I thought this must have been asked before but couldn't find it via [google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=make+%3Awq+equivalent+to+%3AWq "my search string")